# Where do I ask for a verification of de-registration?

Tags: immigration, netherlands, documentation, departure

After living in the Netherlands for several years (and being pretty active on expats.SX as well...) - I've left, earlier this year.

Now, I've de-registered myself as a resident, by filing a Declaration of Deregistration (via IAmsterdam.nl); but - I don't have a signed official government or even municipal document verifying I am deregistered starting on a certain date?

I was told I should ask for an "extract from the Registry of Non-Residents (RNI)", but - how do I do that? (Without physically being in the Netherlands I mean.)

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently I had also gotten a link and missed it. The link is:

https://formulieren.amsterdam.nl/TriplEforms/DirectRegelen/formulier/nl-NL/evAmsterdam/scUittrekselsRNI.aspx

but this may only be relevant to people who had been living in Amsterdam.