# What kind of an RNI extract should I order?

Tags: netherlands, costs, departure, forms

After leaving the Netherlands, I'm trying to get an official verification of my de-registering as a resident - an extract from the "Registry of Non-Residents" (RNI).

I've [figured out](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15337/where-do-i-ask-for-a-verification-of-de-registration) how to ask for this extract. But now I face a new problem: There seem to be multiple kinds of extracts I can order; and each one costs a bit of money. The options, appearing in the screenshot below, are:

- Extract with BSN
- Extract with historical address details (since 1994)
- International extract with personal status (Dutch-French-German-English)

I probably need either the first or the third. But - I can't decide!

[image]

Comment: *I'm trying to get an official verification of my de-registering as a resident* **What for?** That information is needed to answer the question.

Comment: @JanDoggen: Multiple things - both in the Netherlands and abroad. Getting reimbursement for municipal taxes for example; various potential administrative issues in Israel.

Comment: It seems that it still might depend on what the "various administrative issues" are.  But €12.20 isn't a lot of money.  Why not get both, or all three?

Answer (score 1):

If we mouse-over the question-mark links, or read [this form](https://www.breda.nl/en/file/78397/download), this is what each of the extracts contains:

- **Extract with citizen service number**:
   Extract with your name, date of birth, place of birth, country of birth, gender, nationality, citizen service number (BSN), current  address.
- **Extract with historical addresses**:
   Extract with your name, date of birth, citizen service number (BSN), your current foreign address (if known) and all addresses you  have been registered at from 1 October 1994 until date of deregistration in the Netherlands.
- **International extract with marital state (Dutch-French-German-English)**:
   Extract in four different languages with your name, date of birth, marital state (on date of leaving the Netherlands), nationality/ nationalities, names of your parents and date of deregistration in the Netherlands.
- **International extract with marital state (Dutch-Spanish-Italian-Turkish)**:
   Same as the above, but in a different set of languages.

It seems to me that the **date of deregistration** is a key figure, so I *think* the third kind of extract ("International" with English) is the one to choose (or the fourth if your country likes Spanish, Italian or Turkish better).